# AngularJS strict filter on only one field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a form with multiple filters but for some, I need a strict comparison.

**tl;dr**: strict comparison for `user_id` not for `firstname`.

```
<select ng-model="search.user_id">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>

<input type="text" ng-model="search.firstname">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">#{{ user.user_id }} {{ user.firstname}}</li>
</ul>
```

I tried the third parameter `true` but it also works for `firstname` filter.

The problem is: if you select the value `2`, all users with a `2` in their id will be filtered, I don't want this behavior.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErPPz/).

Comment: create a custom filter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i have tried to fix it natively, rather than with custom filters, its working, here's the [PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/kyprfBQUson195gPlBiE?p=preview)

had to specify multiple filters tag

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{'user_id':  search.user_id}: true | filter: {'firstname' : search.firstname}">
```

though there are few caveats:

1. i had to change the type from number to string...
2. if i reset the value of exact match it doesnt work...

so then i had to write a custom filer which works for exact match & ignores empty/null values

```
$scope.filter2 = function(field1, field2) {
  if(field2 === "" || field2 === null) return true;
  return field1 === field2;
};
```

you would find both of them in the provided plunker link

Answer (score 1):

You could have a function like this in your controller

```
$scope.identical = function(actual, expected){
    return actual === parseInt(expected);
}
```

and then you could use it like this

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search.user_id:identical">
```

Comment: This will not filter the `firstname`.

Comment: I believe he writes "strict comparison for user_id not for firstname". And I believe the syntax will work since I tried it in his own fiddle.

Comment: I've already removed the syntax sentence from my comment, my bad not to test before commenting! For the `strict comparision for user_id not for firstname`, not sure what the OP actually need, but my interpretation is that he want to filter by both `user_id` and `firstname` but use the strict comparison on `user_id` only.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cant comment on others answers I will do it this way.

I used HarisR's solution but I modified it so it can be used with numbers also if you need your value as number.

```
$scope.filter2 = function(field1, field2) {
  if(field2 === "" || field2 === null) return true;
  return field1.toString() === field2;
};
```

or

```
$scope.filter2 = function(field1, field2) {
  if(field2 === "" || field2 === null) return true;
  return ""+field1 === field2;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when I loaded some form configuration from Json and the numbers were passed inn as number not String.

```
<div ng-repeat="selectedComponent from ctrl.drivers.components |
     filter:{
             manufacturer: component.manufacturer, 
             type: component.type}:true">
```

When i had a component type of 1 and 10 both would show up in my ng-repeat before I added the `:true` to my filter, and nothing when i had added strict equality.

To fix this I added a method to my controller called castToInt

```
ctrl.castToInt = function(value){
    return parseInt(value);
};
```

Then i modified my filter to show

```
<div ng-repeat="selectedComponent from ctrl.drivers.components |
     filter:{
             manufacturer: component.manufacturer, 
             type: ctrl.castToInt(component.type)}:true">
```

Voila then it all worked

My guess is that `:true` enforces strict equality `===` so you will get a false if you compare different types.

If you can accept to change the type of your value then the accepted answer is sufficent, but if you have no control over the data that is presented to you this method works.

--
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Change in your html:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:f">#{{ user.user_id }} {{ user.firstname}}</li>
```

I assume you want `and` if both values are present. Change it to an `or` if you need to. Custom filter function:

```
$scope.f = function(val) {
    var hasUserId = $scope.search.user_id;
    var hasName = $scope.search.firstname;

    var firstNameMatch = function() { return val.firstname.indexOf($scope.search.firstname) > -1 };
    var userIdMatch = function() { return $scope.search.user_id == val.user_id };

    if(hasUserId && hasName) {
       return  firstNameMatch() && userIdMatch()
    } else if (hasUserId) {
        return userIdMatch();
    } else if (hasName) {
        return firstNameMatch();
    }
    return true;
};
```

One more change to your controller:

```
$scope.search= {};
```

[Forked Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wjX3G/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search by name for example just add a textbox with name= search.yourFieldNameToName, if you want to search in all fields just create an textbox with search.$ and then just add filter:search:strict on your ng-repeat directive.

Sample Code To explain better:

```
<div class="customers view">
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h3>Customers</h3>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            Search All:
            <input data-ng-model="search.$" type="text" placeholder="All Search" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            Search By Name: 
            <input data-ng-model="search.firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name Search" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            Search By LastName:
            <input data-ng-model="search.lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name Search" />                
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            Search By City:
            <input data-ng-model="search.city" type="text" placeholder="City Search" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="row cardContainer">
            <div class="span3 card" data-ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:search:strict | orderBy:'firstName'">
                <button class="btn close cardClose" data-ng-click="deleteCustomer(customer.id)">&times;</button>
                <div class="cardHeader">{{customer.firstName + ' ' + customer.lastName}}</div>
                <div class="cardBody">{{customer.city}}</div>
                <a href="#/customerorders/{{customer.id}}" class="cardBody btn-link">View {{ customer.orders.length }} Orders</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```